Amazon Linux 2023 and SkiaSharp compatibility issues
My Project is .net core 6 MVC，I use the SkiaSharp package for image compression，The program code is as follows，The version of the relevant installation package is SkiaSharp(2.88.8)、 SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux(2.88.8)、SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies(2.88.8)。
There is no problem executing this project on the Linux Ubuntu 22.04 platform on vmware, but when executing it on Amazon Linux 2023,I get this error message:"The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKAbstractManagedStream' threw an exception"
How to solve this problem?
public void CompressPicAndDelOrg(string source, string target, decimal maxWidth, int quality, ref string lsReturnbase64)
 {
     try
     {
         var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
         if (!provider.TryGetContentType(source, out string? mimeType)) mimeType = "application/octet-stream";

         using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(source))
         using (var fileStream = new SKManagedStream(file))
         using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(fileStream))
         {
             var width = (decimal)bitmap.Width;
             var height = (decimal)bitmap.Height;
             var newWidth = width;
             var newHeight = height;

             if (width > maxWidth)
             {
                 newWidth = maxWidth;
                 newHeight = height / width * maxWidth;
             }

             using (var resized = bitmap.Resize(new SKImageInfo((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight), SKFilterQuality.Medium))
             {
                 if (resized != null)
                 {
                     using (var image = SKImage.FromBitmap(resized))
                     using (var writeStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(target))
                     {
                         var lsBase64Temp = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, quality);
                         string lsBase64TempToArray = Convert.ToBase64String(lsBase64Temp.ToArray());
                         lsReturnbase64 = $"data:{mimeType};base64,{lsBase64TempToArray}";
                         image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg, quality).SaveTo(writeStream);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

     }
     catch(Exception ex) 
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Error:" + ex.Message);       
     }
}

It is also a Linux system. For the SkiaSharp package, why is there no problem on the ubuntu 22.04 platform, but there is a problem on Amazon linux 2023? I want to find clues and methods to solve this problem.

Can you post the full stack trace?

16:47:11 INF] Error occurred: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKAbstractManagedStream' threw an exception.

I just tested it on ubuntu22.04 platform on aws ec2, and it’s still no problem
